# Heavy noise from the tappet of my RE Classic 350

Tags: engine, motorcycle, noise, enfield-classic, royal-enfield

I own a Royal Enfield Classic 350 (2014 model). After completing 10000 km, I started hearing an irritating sound from the tappet (service guys says so). At that time it didn't last long, so I thought it will end soon. After completing 15000 km it increased and now I am facing a nonstop horrible sound from the tappet. I just lost the belief in my bull.

- Is there any way that I can end this sound?
- Does changing the tappet will end this?

Comment: I'll let @DucatiKiller answer this, but usually, it would just be an adjustment  in the valvetrain is all that's needed. Again, I could be wrong, as I'm not a motorcycle guy.

Comment: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/12507/tick-tick-sound-from-a-royal-enfield-classic-350-at-idle

Answer (score 2):

**You can adjust your valve lash**

You have nothing to worry about.  Adjusting valve lash is a standard maintenance item and should be done upon any maintenance or tune up's of your vehicle.

As you can see in the image, getting to the adjustment is quite simple.

From there, follow your factory manual regarding reducing the amount of valve lash clearance.

Your motorcycle will be and is fine.  The sounds are normal and can be reduced.

[image]